# Green faces in edit mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

<sub><strike>I pressed something and then</strike></sub> 
The faces of my object appear **green** in *edit mode*. How can I revert that? Newly added objects appear with gray faces in edit mode.

[image: problematic face]

It is not

- a matcap
- a material
- a texture
- vertex color
- object color,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have marked your face as a freestyle face.

Either unmark it, by <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> selecting it and pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> in edit mode to open the face menu. In the face menu choose **clear freestyle face**. You can also untick Face Marks in the mesh display options, if you only want to hide the face marks.

[image: clear freestyle face]